# ROS python control for drcsim2.5

Tags: control, python

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've been following the python tutorial to the letter:
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/2.5/Atlas_control_over_ROS_topics_with_python

But when I try to test it, it goes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "traj_yaml.py", line 4, in <module>
    from atlas_msgs.msg import AtlasCommand
ImportError: No module named atlas_msgs.msg
```

What can I do to solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2847/ros-python-control-for-drcsim2.5/) by [David Jeang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/349/david-jeang/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 34 on 2013-05-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-05-17**:
Have you sourced the drcsim setup.sh file? That is necessary in order to use the tutorial.

**Comment by [David Jeang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/349/david-jeang/) on 2013-05-20**:
Yes I have, as I've said, I've followed the tutorial to the letter, that includes sourcing the drc.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-05-21**:
There should be a manifest.xml in your tutorial_atlas_control folder. Can you paste a copy of it? Also, can you try `roscd atlas_msgs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Issue has been resolved. Several dependencies were missing because I unpacked directly from the source for a specific version.

---

Originally posted by [David Jeang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/349/david-jeang/) with karma: 34 on 2013-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0